# How can I test component @Input in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've done this plenty of times with no problems, but for some reason, I can't get this to work.  In my component I have an input `@Input data: Data`, and in my template I use that input to conditionally show or hide content.  For some reason in my tests, the component won't register that the data is there even if I set it directly with `component.data = {props: values}`, however if I run the tests individually with `fit`, they run fine.

**data.component.spec.ts**

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = testbed.createComponent(DataComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.data = {values: ['a', 'b', 'c']};
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  describe('when viewing', () => {
    it('should load and display data', () => {
      const el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('[data-content]'));
      expect(el).toBeTruthy();
    });
  }
```

**data.component.ts**

```
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data!: Data;

  constructor() {};
  
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('init');
  }
}
```

**data.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="data.values.length">
  <p data-content *ngFor="let value of data.values">{{value}}</p>
</div>
```

**The error I'm getting:**
`Expected null to not be null "[data-content]"`

Comment: Are you importing the CommonModule into your tests so that the ngIf directive is available?

Comment: @rook218 I am, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking it could be because you're calling `fixture.detectChanges` and `ngOnInit`. The first `fixture.detectChanges` you call, calls `ngOnInit` for you.

Try this:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = testbed.createComponent(DataComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.data = {values: ['a', 'b', 'c']};
    fixture.detectChanges(); // => this will call ngOnInit
    // component.ngOnInit(); // remove this line, the first fixture.detectChanges()
    // calls ngOnInit for you.
  });

  describe('when viewing', () => {
    it('should load and display data', () => {
      const el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('[data-content]'));
      expect(el).toBeTruthy();
    });
  }
```

Comment: No change.  It seems to be random failures as well.  Sometimes 1 or 2 tests will pass and other times they'll all fail, even without making code changes.